# Temple run 2 different sounds when executing a sequence after getting a diamond

Tags: temple-run-2

I've noticed a different sound in temple run 2 when I do a certain sequence. I haven't figured it all out yet, and don't see any references to it online.

I usually run with the gem power-up. When I'm in the water, and trigger my power-up, I sometimes have to duck. When I do, I hear a totally different sound. This made me wonder, so next time I heard it, I swiped up, and got another different sound. I think the next step in the sequence is down again, but that's as far as I've gotten.

**TL;DR:** try executing this sequence in a water slide. (Once you start, do it quickly, it seems to only have a few second to do it all.)

1. Trigger a power (only gem power?)
2. Quickly swipe down, then
3. Swipe up, then
4. Swipe down, then
5. ?

Does anyone know the full sequence, and what happens when you do it?

**Update**

I don't know if this is because of the new version, or if I was just totally ignorant of this in the past, but the sound is associated with any time you get at least one diamond.  If you use the skill on the ground and then jump, you'll hear the sound and can just barely get to hear the sound if you subsequently slide.  You can also get the same effect after jumping for a garden.  It's much easier to go up-down repeatedly in the water and hear it there, though.  I still don't know why this sound is in there, but it's not just related to water slides.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer instead of an edit to the question

Comment: Yet the question still stands; maybe I need to clarify it: What purpose are the extra sounds when you get a diamond?  I felt the update was more appropriate than an answer.